# RubyMine Remote SDK with docker-compose finds and sets up correctly, but terminates the rspec

Tags: ruby, docker, docker-compose, rubymine

I have set up docker-compose with my SDK, as per the IntellJ Instructions,  and it found and indexed the gems. Shows the list, and log states that it is installing.
However when I go to run the specs, I get the following error.

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:265:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem rspec-core (>= 0.a) with executable rspec (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:284:in `activate_bin_path'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin/rspec:25:in `<main>'
```

I know that the gems are installed in the docker image, but I feel like either it's not running bundle exec in the proper directory.

The docker-compose will also run the tests from the CLI.

I feel like there is some setting that isn't correct.

I have changed the build configuration to run in the proper directory ( it's a standard rails app nested in a parent directory )

Comment: Could you check whether it works or not with the sample app from the RubyMine's tutorial: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html ?Which RubyMine version are you running?

Comment: Latest version. I have stepped through one problem. The Dockerfile had ruby installed in a weird place.  Im finding it difficult to run the specs w/ the same speed as running it in a native environment. I have changed the command from run to exec and slide into the running container.